# Android on demand permission request

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-security

How to handle **don't ask me again** in android on demand permission request. Is their any best practice if the user chooses **don't ask me again** and later if he want to get access any best practice suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` will help you with this.

`shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` will be used to check whether user have selected **Never ask again**. It will return value as True or False, If user have selected Never ask before it will return false, else will return true.

```
boolean shouldShow = shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
if (!shouldShow) {
    // show some dialog which will give information about required permission, so that user can understand what is need of that permission.
}
```

on button click of dialog, you can redirect user to setting screen of app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you are working for pre-marshmallow, you need to use `ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()`